# c3 x-axis text is very large on chrome

Tags: c3.js

We used C3 charts in one of our projects, but after I upgraded chrome to latest version I got an issue, the chart renders very large text size for x-axis and once I resized the browser it renders correctly.

Any help please.

[Chart Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeeOZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the reason for this unexpected behaver I just removed below attribute from the parent  then everything works probably

```
data-uk-grid="{gutter: 20}"
```